# is there an error with jQuery Tools Scrollable wizard error?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable

I'm trying to implement a wizard for the current web application i'm working on.

Everything works great when there are 3 items(panes) in the list.
When I add the 4th item (titled Finalize), the panel "flies" by super fast and then I'm presented with a blank white screen.

I should also note that I was trying this with FIREFOX, Chrome and Internet Explore 8. They all seem to error out differently..

A working DEMO is here:

http://www.fusze.com/debug_scroller

I feel like this may be a problem with my CSS, but am unsure..

Thank you very much in advance,
Kirk

Comment: When I try to access the demo, the connection times out...

Comment: Yea sorry, the Linode VPS it was on was down all last night from the attacks. Try again now if you like, and thanks!